# Making changes to a built-in Android apps

Tags: android

I've pulled and compiled the latest Android tree.  Now I want to make changes to the Android's Browser application.

The environment in Eclipse is already set up.  I tried creating the project by selecting "Build project from existing source", but it fails to build because it uses libraries not in the SDK.

Does anyone know how to import the missing source in order to build the Browser app, or even better, how to just copy the source into a separate project and use it like I was developing a regular application?

Answer (score 0):

> Does anyone know how to import the missing source in order to build the Browser app

That is not possible. The "missing source" is the operating system.

> how to just copy the source into a separate project and use it like I was developing a regular application?

That too is not possible.

You cannot just grab an app out of the Android open source project and build it via the SDK. Some of the apps were first written before the SDK existed. Other apps rely upon APIs that, for various reasons, have not yet been exposed in the SDK.

You are welcome to make modifications to the Browser app. However, to build them, you need to use the build process for the firmware, not treat it as a regular SDK-based project.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I have one more question: is putting the altered browser on a phone any different than a regular application?

Comment: @Vax456: Unless you put the application into a new package, you can't put it on a phone. You do not have the device manufacturer's signing key, which is required for replacing a built-in app. If you build complete firmware, and your phone supports alternative firmware, you could load that firmware on it. Or, if you move the application to another package (e.g., `com.vax456.browser`), you should be able to install it as a normal application, though this will massively complicate your build process.